# How do I catch exceptions if thrown in @BeforeMethod or @BeforeClass without using a TestNGListener

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have a test class each for a specific functionality and have layers of Test Classes that are considered as BaseClass wherein the driver initialization and test kickoff happens (I avoided using Listener here). Defined an AfterMethod in BaseClass which logs out and also captures the results with the exceptions and stacktrace and logs to a database, if the test fails I am able to capture the exceptions, the exceptions are not caught if the BeforeMethod or BeforeClass fails, all I see is test status which is shown as SKIPPED. Here is the piece of code that I use in AfterMethod:

```
public void afterMethodBase(ITestResult result) { 
        logger.debug("TestName : " + result.getTestName());
        logger.info("Method Name : " + result.getMethod().getMethodName());
        ResultLogger.processResult(result);
        Throwable exception = itr.getThrowable(); // this is null when status is skipped
}
```

How to catch the exceptions raised in `BeforeMethod` or `BeforeClass`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a listener with its appropriate method: [`IConfigurationListener#onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult)`](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IConfigurationListener.html#onConfigurationFailure-org.testng.ITestResult-)

Check [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) for more details about listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If accessing it via the Listeners is not something that you want to do, then why not access them like this ?

From the `ITestResult` object that get through your `@AfterMethod` annotated method:

- First get hold of all the failed configuration methods via `result.getTestContext().getFailedConfigurations().getAllMethods()`
- Then you iterate through the above collection of `ITestNGMethod` to filter out only `@BeforeClass` failures by calling `org.testng.ITestNGMethod#isBeforeClassConfiguration`